# Datatable Material and Angular problem for displaying data

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem displaying the data from the get in my table. The GET works without any problem, I tested it, the problem is that the array has to be generated after the user has selected a value in a mat-option.
Once the mat-option is selected, a get retrieves the data and that's when the array must be built.
Being totally new to Angular, I don't see what I need to do for this initialization which has to be outside OnInit().

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RestApiService } from '../shared/rest-api.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, startWith, debounceTime, switchMap, map, filter, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-services-namespace',
  templateUrl: './services-namespace.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services-namespace.component.scss']
})

export class ServicesNamespaceComponent implements OnInit {
  
  myControl = new FormControl();
  myControl2 = new FormControl();
  options = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;
  namespaces = [];
  services: Observable<any[]>;
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'service'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;



  constructor(private dataService: RestApiService) {
     this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(val => {
            return this.filter(val || '')
       }) 
    )
   }

   ngOnInit() { 
     
  }
  

  filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
    // call the service which makes the http-request
    return this.dataService.getAllNameSpaces()
     .pipe(
       map(response => response.filter(option => { 
         return option.namespace.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
       }))
     )
     
   }  


   getServices(namespace){   
    this.services = this.dataService.getAllServices("services");  
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  


}
```

```
 <!-- WORKING -->
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Namespace" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" > 
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getServices($event.option.value)'>
<mat-progress-bar mode="buffer"></mat-progress-bar>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.namespace">
        {{option.namespace}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>


 <!-- WORKING -->
<form class="example-form" *ngIf="services">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Namespace" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl2" [matAutocomplete]="auto2" > 
    <mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete">
<mat-progress-bar mode="buffer"></mat-progress-bar>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let service of services | async" [value]="service.service">
        {{service.service}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>




  <!-- EMPTY -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="services">
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id" *ngFor="let service of services | async">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let service"> {{service.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="service" *ngFor="let service of services | async">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let service"> {{service.service}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <!-- Angular 8 pagination -->
  <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Console Error(that appears after the user selection) :

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined
    at ServicesNamespaceComponent.getServices (services-namespace.component.ts:70)
    at ServicesNamespaceComponent_Template_mat_autocomplete_optionSelected_3_listener (services-namespace.component.html:10)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21965)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:22007)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:37329)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at EventEmitter.next (Subject.js:39)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6272
handleError @ core.js:6325
handleError @ core.js:13721
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:21968
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:22007
schedulerFn @ core.js:37329
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:37237
_emitSelectEvent @ autocomplete.js:263
_setValueAndClose @ autocomplete.js:1107
(anonymous) @ autocomplete.js:1055
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ take.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ switchMap.js:70
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ map.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:72
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:72
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
schedulerFn @ core.js:37277
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:37237
_emitSelectionChangeEvent @ core.js:3313
_selectViaInteraction @ core.js:3255
MatOption_click_HostBindingHandler @ core.js:3318
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:21965
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:22007
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:976
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41794
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1647
Show 22 more frames
core.js:12658 Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.
logUnknownPropertyError @ core.js:12658
elementPropertyInternal @ core.js:12528
ɵɵproperty @ core.js:21195
ServicesNamespaceComponent_table_10_Template @ services-namespace.component.html:50
executeTemplate @ core.js:12019
refreshView @ core.js:11858
refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews @ core.js:13250
refreshView @ core.js:11885
detectChangesInternal @ core.js:13562
detectChanges @ core.js:15203
closePanel @ autocomplete.js:770
_setValueAndClose @ autocomplete.js:1109
(anonymous) @ autocomplete.js:1055
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ take.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ switchMap.js:70
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ map.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:72
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:72
_next @ InnerSubscriber.js:11
next @ Subscriber.js:49
schedulerFn @ core.js:37277
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:37237
_emitSelectionChangeEvent @ core.js:3313
_selectViaInteraction @ core.js:3255
MatOption_click_HostBindingHandler @ core.js:3318
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:21965
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:22007
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:976
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41794
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1647
Show 20 more frames
core.js:12658 Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.
```

Imports are OK, the table is displaying good but without data

Comment: I cant see the paginator in your html. Can you post your full code of Mat table?

Comment: The paginator is in the code @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
It's displayed too. The problem is just how to init the table after the getServices(namespace) :) 
The table has to be loading after this get that returns the data

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `ViewChild` on paginator but u dont have it on html. That's why you have this error

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined
```

To solve this, just simple add this after `Mat Table`

```
 <mat-paginator #paginatorName [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]">
```

and in your .ts

```
  @ViewChild("paginatorName") paginatorName : MatPaginator;
```

Also you need to initialize your `MatTableDataSource`. and I assume your table data is `observable`.
First initialize your MatTableDataSource  and placed it to `onInit()`

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
}
```

And in your `getServices`

```
getServices(namespace){
    this.services = this.dataService.getAllServices("services")
        .subscribe(response =>  this.dataSource.data = response);
}
```

Add an `ngAfterViewInit` to set paginator and sort of table

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Also check this. I updated your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8rzmja-sh6m8p

Comment: I made a mistake in my first post, the HTML has been editer, i tried with your #paginator too but "can't bind" error stays.

This thing is not the problem the problem is that in my case i don't have a table on the init but after the selection of the user.
So how to modify my code to start the table when the data is ready ?

Comment: you need to solve your paginator error first before jumping to another problem

Comment: So what you want is when you select a record on mat option then the table will load?

Comment: No there is not at all any problem with the paginator. Your paginator name is useful only with multi datatable not in my case.
This is a stackblitz(not mine, but updated for my use) https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyyxdgpbjyxo  of what i'm doing. The difference between the stackblitz and my code is only the load after the user instead on oninit.

Comment: Yes when the user select a record, it start the method getServices(namespace) witch contains the data !
And it generates the datatable with this data

Comment: This one is now mine, you can see working without any problem in case of oninit 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8rzmja

Comment: For your last edit sry but no not working same result, and there is no need of subscribe. I have async witch is better.

Comment: No compilation, it's logical, changes are not good, the subscribe has not to be there, too much error for comment. We are creating errors, i'm not sure that you look my code for purposing me "subscribe.." 
Please understand that the blackblitz works. And the only difference is that in my case i don't want to load it at init but after the user selection.

Comment: Hi. I can see where you bind data to you datasource and filteredOption.

Comment: @acer23 I just see your stack, but my get method is like that : 
public getAllServices(namespace) {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER_BASE_LINK + '/' + namespace).pipe(tap(data => this.data = data));
  }

So on get side : 
getServices(namespace) {         
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataService.getAllServices("services"); 
  }

The error on dataSource.data is : Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more